# How do I use SQL and virtual layer to draw a line from one polygon to another in the same layer?

Tags: virtual-layer, st-makeline, swmm

Background:
Sometimes in modelling hydrology (e.g. in SWMM) we have runon from one subcatchment area to another. These subcatchments are records in a shapefile. I want to show this situation as a line from the centroid of one polygon to another (the "outlet"). This is what I tried (which obviously doesn't work):

```
select make_line(st_centroid(Subcatchments.geometry),st_centroid(Subcatchments.geometry))
from Subcatchments
where Subcatchments.OUTLET = Subcatchments.Name
```

Can anybody assist me in how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to join the layer to itself:

```sql
SELECT make_line(st_centroid(s1.geometry),st_centroid(s2.geometry))
FROM Subcatchments s1
JOIN Subcatchments s2 
 ON s1.OUTLET = s2.Name
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was trying to do–I just couldn't quite figure out how.